# Using "forEach" instead of "for-In" in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use `forEach` to refactor:

```
for item in results! {

  guard let color = item["Color"] else {return}
  guard let timeDateString = item["TimeDate"] else {return}
  let timeDate = timeDateString as! Date
  let timeDateFormatted = timeDate.shortDateTime

  self.colorArray.append(teamColor as! String)
  self.timeDateFormattedArray.append(timeDateFormatted)

  let gate = Gate(color: color as! String, timeDateString: timeDateFormatted)
  self.gateArray.append(gate)                   
}
```

Into a much simpler, more Swifty version:

```
guard let unwrappedResults = results else { return }
unwrappedResults.forEach{
  let gateM = Gate(color: $0["Color"] as! String, timeDateString: ((($0["TimeDate"]) as! Date).shortDateTime) as! String)
  self.gateArrayOther.append(gateM)
}
```

But I get a **crash** related to my `timeDateString` :

**"Could not cast value of type __NSTaggedDate to NSString"**

I think I understand the error, but I can't figure my way around it using a variety of things I've tried inside of the `forEach` statement.  Any ideas?

Here is my struct if needed:

```
struct Gate {
    var color: String
    var timeDate: Any
    var timeDateString: String
}
```

`unwrappedResults` logged per @matt dynamite suggestion for clarity and essential helpfulness for all to see:

```
values={
    Color = CC0033;
    TimeDate = "2017-04-11 19:30:00 +0000";
}, recordType=Playoffs>
{
    READ-ONLY
    creatorUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x608000232160; recordName=_048b3b79056e097ae45e5d7365c2d5c4, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    lastModifiedUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x608000232300; recordName=_048b3b79056e097ae45e5d7365c2d5c4, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    creationDate -> 2015-09-19 20:54:44 +0000
    modificationDate -> 2017-01-07 19:18:27 +0000
    modifiedByDevice -> 2
    Color -> "CC0033"
    TimeDate -> 2017-04-11 19:30:00 +0000
}, <CKRecord: 0x7fcc2a50b620; recordID=e26c7ef0-836e-4bd1-9d1d-13e0f2b63320:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=ierdnqjo, values={
    Color = FDB927;
    TimeDate = "2017-04-11 23:30:00 +0000";
}, recordType=Playoffs>
{
    READ-ONLY
    creatorUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x600000031da0; recordName=_048b3b79056e097ae45e5d7365c2d5c4, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    lastModifiedUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x600000031be0; recordName=_048b3b79056e097ae45e5d7365c2d5c4, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    creationDate -> 2015-09-19 17:57:15 +0000
    modificationDate -> 2017-01-07 19:18:43 +0000
    modifiedByDevice -> 2
    Color -> "FDB927"
    TimeDate -> 2017-04-11 23:30:00 +0000
    MatchupHome -> "GST"
}, <CKRecord: 0x7fcc2a704d30; recordID=8dd9b376-66f4-4e50-b95b-bf50c685eebb:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=ierq50xa, values={

    Color = E3263A;
    TimeDate = "2017-04-12 03:30:00 +0000";
}, recordType=Playoffs>
{
    READ-ONLY
    creatorUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x60800002dfe0; recordName=_048b3b79056e097ae45e5d7365c2d5c4, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    lastModifiedUserRecordID -> <CKRecordID: 0x60800002ec00; recordName=_048b3b79056e097ae45e5d7365c2d5c4, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>
    creationDate -> 2015-09-19 23:46:37 +0000
    modificationDate -> 2017-01-07 19:17:25 +0000
    modifiedByDevice -> 2
    Color -> "E3263A"
    TimeDate -> 2017-04-12 03:30:00 +0000
}]
```

Comment: Please log `unwrappedResults` for us.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I don't think your `forEach` is any simpler than the `for` loop.

Comment: This is _not_ your real code: `let gateM = Gate(color: $0["Color"] as! String, timeDateString: timeDateString: ((($0["TimeDate"]) as! Date).shortDateTime) as! String)` If it were, you could not compile. _Please show only your real code_. Copy and _paste_ right into the question. Thank you.

Comment: @kennytm thanks for the helpful feedback, maybe I was going too far trying to get it Swifty.  Just trying to learn and get better, and maybe I'm making it more complicated by trying to make it more simple.

Comment: @matt absolutely unacceptable/bad paste, so sorry! Viewers time is valuable, if I'm asking for help, I need to be better! Also logged unwrappedResults for all to see. Thanks!!!

Comment: @SRMR more swifty would be to `map` instead of `forEach` + `append`

Comment: @Alistra thanks for the response! I'm all about getting it more swifty so thank you for the tip.  I'm not sure how I'd leave out `append` if I just did map, can you give any pointers on how you're seeing it play out in the code?

Comment: i posted an answer - maybe that fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that your code before converting is valid.

note: i need to guess some classes of your solution

#### 1. Solution

```
func getTimeDateFormatted(itemTimeDate: Any?) -> String? {
    guard let timeDateString = itemTimeDate else { return nil}
    let timeDate = timeDateString as! Date
    let timeDateFormatted = timeDate.debugDescription
    return timeDateFormatted
}
```

this struct

```
struct Gate {
    var color: String
    var timeDate: Any
    var timeDateString: String
}
```

then you can make it more swiftful it into

```
func abc(results:[[String:Any]]? ) -> [Gate]?{
    guard let unwrappedResults = results else { return nil }
    let gateArrayOther = unwrappedResults.map{
        Gate(color: $0["Color"] as! String,
             timeDate: $0["TimeDate"] as Any,
             timeDateString: getTimeDateFormatted(itemTimeDate: $0["TimeDate"]) ?? "")
    }
    return gateArrayOther
}
```

#### 2. Solution

add time convert into the struct

```
func getTimeDateFormatted(itemTimeDate: Any?) -> String? {
    guard let timeDateString = itemTimeDate else { return nil}
    let timeDate = timeDateString as! Date
    let timeDateFormatted = timeDate.debugDescription
    return timeDateFormatted
}

struct Gate {
    var color: String
    var timeDate: Any
    var timeDateString: String
    init(color: String, timeDate: Any){
        self.color = color
        self.timeDate = timeDate
        self.timeDateString = getTimeDateFormatted(itemTimeDate: timeDate) ?? ""
    }
}

func def(results:[[String:Any]]? ) -> [Gate]?{

    guard let unwrappedResults = results else { return nil}
    let gateArrayOther = unwrappedResults.map{
        Gate(color: $0["Color"] as! String,
             timeDate: $0["TimeDate"] as Any)
    }
    return gateArrayOther
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Great answer, works seamlessly and is clear!

Comment: which solution you implmented?

Comment: I used #1 for now, but I think I'm going to try out #2 too